# Coupons applying outside of date range and active state

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, bug, date

I have some shopping cart price rules set up and want to limit the date range.

- I have set up my rule to apply a 15% discount on a given SKU, this is working.
- I have a date range setup from a week out from the given day, this is NOT working.

The rule is being applied outside of the Start and End Date.

- Setting the rule to 'Inactive' does not deactivate the shopping cart price rule.
- Changing the groups which can use the coupon DOES have effect on the coupon.

I'd really appreciate any feedback so I don't have to schedule myself to activate these rules by choosing which groups are allowed to use them on the day that the promotion goes live.

I am using Magento CE 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to CE 1.9.1 and it resolved the issues.

If a more complete upgrade is not a good idea - please view:
https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix

Answer (score 1):

Maybe need actualize **Special price**, and can using only special_price

Seems, ***Date range*** not works in Rules filter

Maybe will helpfull -

[Catalog price rule from today does not apply](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61045/catalog-price-rule-from-today-does-not-apply/104811#104811)

Comment: please see my answer below.  Issue resolved in 1.9.1